# ZIP file with metadata?

Tags: zip, metadata, timestamp

Is there any standard way to store metadata (e.g. timestamps) inside ZIP files, along with the files?

What program would I need to use in order to do this?

Comment: Tempted to -1 for not doing even basic research...

Comment: @grawity: What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: He is talking about downvoting your question since you failed to share what you've already researched on that subject. I added the part where you ask about a specific application – it seems to be the real issue here – is that okay?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It's called the ["Extra" field](http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/0610242300.aspx)

Many different programs use that field for their own purposes; we can't recommend one if we don't know what goals you have.

Answer (score 1):

A Java JAR manifest is a metadata file, and a JAR file is a special form of ZIP file.  Basically, you can put any file you want inside the ZIP file and call it "metadata".

Answer (score -2):

You can always wrap an xml file around the zip which includes the metadata and the path to the zip, give it its own extension and write a default handler for your new extension which gets the meta data then opens the zip.

Comment: … sounds really easy!

Comment: ... o_o I hope you're being sarcastic...